# Kafka client faced disconnected will reconnect again by again, anyway can disable it?

Tags: apache-kafka

The client will reconnect again by itself again, anyway I can disable it?

Should I close Kafka client?

```
[2022-06-30 16:17:51,332] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-xxx, groupId=xxx] Bootstrap broker xxx:xxx (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2022-06-30 16:17:52,387] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-pg-hudi001_5-1, groupId=pg-hudi001_5] Connection to node -1 (xxx) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The consumer will constantly poll and periodically refresh its metadata about what brokers are available from the cluster Controller.

The only way to stop it from trying to connect is to `close()` the consumer, yes.